# Print exponential notation with one leading zero with C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, iostream, exponential

I am generating a text file to be used as a FORTRAN input file. The FORTRAN program specifies that the values it reads must be in a format such that

```
1.0
```

must be printed as

```
0.1000000E+01
```

As of right now the closest I have gotten in using iostream is

```
1.000000E+00
```

with the code

```
cout << setprecision(6) << fixed << scientific << uppercase;
_set_output_format(_TWO_DIGIT_EXPONENT);
cout << 1.0 << endl;
```

Does anyone know the best way to get a leading zero as shown above, preferably using ostream instead of printf?

Comment: If I have to be pedantic, what your FORTRAN code requires is not scientific notation.

Comment: That is true... but that was the easiest way to summarize the problem

Comment: I fear you will have to write a function by yourself, since that is non-standard, unfortunately. Maybe patching the FORTRAN program could be simpler? Or that's not an option?

Comment: Patching the FORTRAN is not an option because it is optimized for CFD processing.

Comment: If I have to be pedantic `1.000000E+01` and `0.100000E+01` are two different numbers. Should it be `1.000000E+00`? I mean if your code `cout << 1 << endl;` put `1.000000E+01`, there is something intersting going on.

Comment: Moreover your code will output just `1` anyways because `cout << 1 << endl;` will use `operator<<(int)` not `float`. `cout << 2.0 << endl;` this gives `2.000000E+00`. Did you really run this code or just made up example, for the sake of the question, lol ?

Comment: As @luk32 points out, the code in your question prints just `1`. Please update your question to show code that actually illustrates the problem.

Comment: I really ran it.. just with 1.0. I edited the question. The actual impementation used all precise (6 digits) numbers so this was just oversight. @luk32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, what you ask is non-standard, but you can achieve that with a trick:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

class Double {
public:
    Double(double x): value(x) {}
    const double value;
};

std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & stream, const Double & x) {
    // So that the log does not scream
    if (x.value == 0.) {
        stream << 0.0;
        return stream;
    }

    int exponent = floor(log10(std::abs(x.value)));
    double base = x.value / pow(10, exponent);

    // Transform here
    base /= 10;
    exponent += 1;

    stream << base << 'E' << exponent; // Change the format as needed

    return stream;
}

int main() {
    // Use it like this
    std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << std::fixed;
    std::cout << Double(-2.203e-15) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The `Double` wrapper is needed because you cannot redefine `<<` for `double`.

I did not test that way of separating `exponent` and `base` against the odds of floating point, maybe you can come up with a better alternative, but you get the idea :)

Comment: Good C++ answer.  I've tried such an approach in the past to deal with similar problems but had trouble with values _close_ to powers of 10.  Values like 0.9999999999e-10 or 1.00000000001-10 come up with a mis-match pair for `exponent` and `base`, especially the `floor(log10...` part.  You may want to try such test cases.

Comment: I was viewing a cached verison. For some reason the first if statement where `x==0` is telling me that no operator matches these operands

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, I fixed it a minute ago or so. Try with the code now.

Comment: Thank you, it now works. I'm a little mad at myself for not catching that simple error.

Comment: @Stefano Values like 0.999999999999 get broken up nicely either way: frexp10 or frexp, but the finite precision setting (6 here), causes `stream << base`  to round and print "1.000000".  `exponent` does not _know_ of this decimal point shift and prints its original value.  It is the _rounding_ of `base`, effectively a math operation, that should also affect `exponent`, but doesn't, that leaves a small hole in this approach.

Comment: The exponent value is not the desired format either but this is a good starting point.

Comment: Yes, you can adjust the `stream << base << 'E' << exponent;` part to suit your needs. @chux objection is correct, unfortunately I couldn't come up with any simple method to perform such an adjustment.

Comment: Please don't edit answers by other users with radical changes like that one :) Besides, you can apply modifiers to the line in the comment above, without those `if`s. Just use `std::setfill`.

Comment: Sorry i'm new here, will remember for future :)

Answer (score 1):

C thought:

Not a great answer because C++ answer preferred.

```
char buf[20];
buf[0] = ' ';
double x = -1.234567;
sprintf(&buf[1], "% .6E", x*10);
if (buf[3] == '.') {  // detect if x was INF or NAN
  buf[0] = buf[1];
  buf[1] = '0';
  buf[3] = buf[2];
  buf[2] = '.';
}

// Cope with leading potential space if needed
if (buf[0] == ' ') memmove(&buf[0], &buf[1], strlen(buf));

printf("%s\n", buf);
// -0.1234567E+00
```

Weakness: Trouble if decimal point is not '.' or x near INF.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a locale facet that prints NO decimal point, and imbue it.
2. `cout << "0." << setprecision(6) << fixed << scientific << uppercase << number * 10;`

Comment: This works, but is seemingly less efficient to set and reset ios flags for every number printed

Comment: Would this print the '-' sign after the "0."?

Comment: I think you can call `.write("0.", 2)` instead of << and not reset everything all the time.

Comment: @chux: yes, my mistake ;) so you need to print `-` manuallly too, and suppress it in the facet.